# R Dataframe: Combine rows / values when two other values match

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Name  Fruit Cost
Adam  Orange   2
Adam  Apple    3
Bob   Orange   3
Cathy Orange   4
Cathy Orange   5
```

Dataframe creation:

```
df=data.frame(Name=c("Adam","Adam","Bob","Cathy","Cathy"),Fruit=c("Orange","Apple","Orange","Orange","Orange"),Cost=c(2,3,3,4,5))
```

I would like to script a combine that says when Name and Fruit match, add the Cost and delete the *other* row. For the example, the result would look like this, with two Cathy costs being combined because the Name and Fruit are the same:

```
Name  Fruit Cost
Adam  Orange   2
Adam  Apple    3
Bob   Orange   3
Cathy Orange   9
```

I was thinking of writing a for loop to compare line by line, value by value, compare and add and then delete. But I have to imagine there's a faster/cleaner way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Cost = sum(Cost)), .(Name, Fruit)]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is sum `Cost` within a group.

In base R:

```
aggregate(Cost ~ Name + Fruit, df, sum)
```

Or using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Name, Fruit) %>% 
  summarize(Cost = sum(Cost), .groups = "drop")
```

Comment: aggregate definitely worked, thanks!  You and Akrun both answered at the same time